# CSS Selectors with Nth Childs

Tags: html, css

I've got the below html:

```
<div class="products_lists">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What this is is simply a container with 3 rows and 3 columns.
I am currently using the following CSS to apply animation on the glyphicons when you hover over the div that contains them:

```
.products_lists .col-sm-4:hover .glyphicon-export{-webkit-animation: tada ease-in-out 1 normal 1000ms;-moz-animation: tada ease-in-out 1 normal 1000ms;-ms-animation: tada ease-in-out 1 normal 1000ms;animation: tada ease-in-out 1 normal 1000ms;}
```

The above css rule though is glyphicon specific... I am trying to create a css rule that would be generic and irrelevant from the glyphicon but i can't seam to make this work...

what i was trying was something like:

```
 .products_lists .row:nth-child(1):hover .glyphicon{ }
```

Can anyone give some help on this?

Comment: you near there, try to change "product_lists" to "products_lists"... ops, people here very fast (!)  look there,  is it (!), and @BlaineRW show that must not use "(:hover)" but only ":hover".

Comment: @PeterKrauss thanks peter, that was a small typo from my end (the plural) i've also tried removing the round brackets but this doesn't do what i am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.products_lists .row:nth-child(1):hover .glyphicon {}
```

This selector should work fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/mvg7L/

Comment: thanks for your answer mate. This code selects the whole row and not the first child of the row, which is the first col-sm-4 div...

Comment: No worries. I see now what you were wanting, and that you've figured out the :nth-child(1) should have been on .col-sm-4 element. Hope I helped! =)

Answer (score 0):

Silly me...

I forgot the to add the class of the columns.

```
.products_lists .row .col-sm-4:nth-child(1):hover .glyphicon
```

Here is the fiddle with the result i wanted just in case anyone else is interested for:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/aLj9D/

Also added the Animate library that i am using.

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Well... I do silly mistakes also, and here "in public" :-) ... But I think you can "accept" @BlaineRW's answer, it is a good clue and correct for your initial (not edited) question.